# Error al filtrar consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Se supone que esta consulta tiene que filtrar por todas las condiciones que están después del `where` o bien combinar las condiciones pero, al momento de yo poner un rango de fecha, un nombre y un título de interacción, los datos no se filtran como deberían.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cl.first_name as Nombre, cl.last_name as apellido,cl.id_personal as Cedula, cl.phone as phone,it.title as interacion, fecha
FROM (SELECT interactions.create_date as fecha FROM interactions WHERE interactions.create_date BETWEEN '2017-10-23' AND '2017-10-23') sa, clients_profile cl left join interactions it ON cl.id = it.id_client_profile
WHERE   cl.first_name = '' OR
        cl.last_name =  '' OR
        cl.phone = '' OR
        cl.id_personal ='' OR
        it.title = '';
```

---

este es un ejemplo del resultado que me da al intentar filtrar por los 2 campos, lo que sucedes es que busco lograr un query donde filtre los datos mediante los parametros y si no envia uno que filtre por al menos 1 que, en este caso seria las fechas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo debería filtrarse y cómo se filtran? Sería ideal si pudieras incluir ejemplos de los datos que tienes en la base de datos, del resultado que esperas y el resultado que obtienes para que pudiéramos ver mejor el problema.

Comment: aqui tengo un ejemplo donde intento filtrar por las fechas y tambien con nombre pero solo me filtra por las fechas

Comment: Quiero preguntarte una cosa: ¿los **tres `delvin capellán vargas`** que aparecen en la imagen son realmente **tres** filas diferentes en la tabla `client_profile` o son producto de un resultado erróneo?  Si me dices que son tres filas diferentes entonces tienes un serio problema en el diseño de tus tablas. Y... otra pregunta: ¿en caso de que haya que modificar la estructura de la base de datos, tienes libertad para hacerlo o tienes que ceñirte a lo que ya existe?

Comment: Los 3 registros que haz mencionado, solo se repiten en la tabla “interactions”, en la tabla clients_profile solo esta una vez.

Comment: @A.Cedano es el join de una persona x 3 interacciones.

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta (simplificada) es

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   cl.first_name as Nombre, 
   cl.last_name as apellido,
   cl.id_personal as Cedula, 
   cl.phone as phone,
   it.title as interacion, 
   fecha
FROM clients_profile cl 
left join interactions it ON cl.id = it.id_client_profile
WHERE   cl.first_name = 'delvin' OR
        it.create_date BETWEEN '2017-10-23' AND '2017-10-23'
```

Está pidiendo todos los registros donde el nombre sea 'delvin' **O** la fecha esté entre las dos fechas que pusiste. El resultado te va a dar todas las interacciones de 'delvin' en toda la eternidad, y todas las interacciones del resto de las personas en el rango de fecha.

Si envías los dos parámetros, entonces la condición debiera ser un **AND** en vez de un **OR**

Comment: entiendo el funcionamiento de las condiciones AND y OR pero donde me perdi un poco es que, busco que mi query trabaje con 1 o mas filtros donde yo mandre a la BD la consulta con 3, 2 o 1 un solo filtro.